# WordPress hook / filter to process link inside a post

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a **hook / filter to process the link being added into a WordPress post** ?

My aim is to **pre-process the link** inserted in a post using the following button and **shorten it using a third party API like bit.ly**

**I want to do this for both internal / external links.**

[image: TinyMCE add link button]

**One solution that I an think of is to add an extra button to my editor** that does this but I would prefer a hook / filter that does the job, that way it would be more clean and I will convert that into a custom plugin for my website (there by allowing my WordPress to be up-gradable).

I went through the WordPress docs and skimmed through the following hooks / filters which were of no use to me

1. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_link/
2. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link/
3. And most of the ones listed here
   https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=link

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update 1**: As far as I know, external URLs are inserted into post content by TinyMCE editor link plugin, PHP does nothing.

In WordPress, there're two plugins which located at `wp-includes/js/wplink.js` and `wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wplink/plugin.js`. Note that if you're not in `SCRIPT_DEBUG` mode, they have `.min` suffix.

1. #### wp-includes/js/wplink.js handles this dialog:

[image: wplink dialog box 1]

To filter URLs inserted via this dialog box, we must override `wpLink.getAttrs` method. For example, to add `so39115564` string to every URLs:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  wpLink.getAttrs = function() {
    wpLink.correctURL();
    return {
      href: $.trim( $("#wp-link-url").val() + "so39115564" ),
      target: $("#wp-link-target").prop("checked") ? "_blank" : ""
    };
  }
});
```

You should take a look at the `wp-includes/js/wplink.js` for more info. It's too long to explain in detail here.

And let say the above script is `mylink.js`, here is how we should enqueue it:

```
add_filter('admin_enqueue_scripts', function()
{
  // { Maybe some conditions for a valid screen here. }

  wp_enqueue_script('mylink', 'link/to/the/mylink.js', ['link'], '1.0', true);
}, 0, 0);
```

2. #### wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wplink/plugin.js handles this dialog:

[image: wplink dialog 2]

This time, we also have to override `setURL` method of `tinymce.ui.WPLinkPreview`. But, it's *almost impossible*, unless you deregister this script and register a modified version. Then manage that script yourself with unpredictable changes from WordPress.

Now, choose it wisely! Shorten any external URLs before pasting them into your posts or mess up with WordPress TinyMCE plugins or use dialog box of `wp-includes/js/wplink.js` plugin.

---

Yes! WordPress inserts inline links via `wp_link_ajax` action which is executed by [wp_ajax_wp_link_ajax()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ajax_wp_link_ajax/) function.

As you can see in source code of that function, `$results` is retrieved by `_WP_Editors::wp_link_query`. Check out this method, you will meet [wp_link_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_link_query/) filter. This filter accept two arguments: `$results` and `$query`. `$results` will be what we need to filter.

For example, we need to append `so39115564` to the queried link:

```
add_filter('wp_link_query', function(array $results, array $query)
{
  $results[0]['permalink'] = $results[0]['permalink'] . 'so39115564';

  return $results;
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 2);
```

Now, you should know how to do it. Make sure to take a look at [_WP_Editors::wp_link_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/_wp_editors/wp_link_query/) to filter the `$results` more efficient.

Comment: While this works for internal linking of posts this only serves as a partial answer. As it is possible to paste an external link as well into the link text box. External link does not call this filter. Up voted for partial answer, will wait for a complete answer or else will accept this in 7 days.

Comment: @divyenduz I have just updated the answer. Hope you can find out the best way!

Comment: I ended up using wp_insert_post_data and wp_link_query. For external links, filtered post content before saving. Thanks, I will accept this answer after waiting for 2 days for another answer.

Comment: I've used this approach and it's a great one. Just adding: `wp_link_query_args` is another filter for the same `_WP_Editors::wp_link_query` that let you alterate query params before they're used to query the DB. Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_link_query_args

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered not processing the link until you save the post? There is an action in the wordpress plugin api called "save_post" that's triggered on save.

Using "save_post" you could parse the content of the post and replace links using a url shortener then.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: I considered that alternative as well but my posts will have many short links (30-50). Doing that in one go will make save_post very slow.

Comment: @divyenduz I think save_post would be the easiest solution considering that making a extra button in the editor requires a tinymce plugin that can be a lot of work to make.

Comment: Thanks, will use this method in case I am unable to find any other solution and mark your answer complete. Will give this question some time though.

Answer (score 1):

There might be plugins available for this , but here is the default logic behind.

> **1st Way : To save the shortened URL in DB also**

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_book_meta', 10, 3 );
function save_book_meta( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $slug = 'event';

    // If this isn't a 'book' post, don't update it.
    if ( $slug != $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    preg_match_all('|<a.*(?=href=\"([^\"]*)\")[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>|i', $post->post_content, $match);

    $new_content = $post->post_content;

    foreach($match[1] as $link){
        $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=AIzaSyAnw98CCy5owhpgB2HvW3SkoXfm0MrLjks';

        $json_data = json_encode( array( 'longUrl' => $link ) );

        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);


        $result = json_decode($result);
        $new_content = str_replace($link, $result->id, $new_content);

    }

    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action('save_post', 'save_book_meta' );

    $post_new = array(
        'ID'       => $post_id,
        'post_content'  => $new_content
      );

    $post_id = wp_update_post( $post_new, true );                         
    if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
        $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
    add_action( 'save_post', 'save_book_meta' );

}
```

To achieve the above thing you will have to do following things :

- Use `save_post` hook to get the post content after saving.
- In this hook fetch all the external links in an array (modify the
  conditions as per requirements).
- Shorten the URL by using google API (key is required).
- Get response from the Google API and update the post_data
  accordingly in the database also.
- At `wp_update_post` we are removing the hook to avoid infinite loop.

> **2nd Way : To show the front-end user shortened URL , (DB will have longUrl though)**

- Use the filter hook instead and with the same logic.

> **3rd Way : Plugin Usage** (Not used personally).

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/url-shortener/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortnit/

Answer (score 1):

I am not perfect in TinyMCE because i didn't used TinyMCE in several project but i have experience with javascript so i found a some TinyMCE event api to use you can make a short url. I checked in WP latest version and TinyMCE version 4.x. You can also find for right api to trigger your custom callback.

Before tinymce initialize in wordpress editor register setup function using wordpress hook **tiny_mce_before_init**.

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_plugin_tiny_mce_before_init' );
function my_plugin_tiny_mce_before_init( $in ){
  $in['setup'] = 'myplugin_tinymce_setup'; // javascript callback 
  return $in;   
}

   add_action( 'admin_footer', 'add_admin_footer' );
```

After add javascript callback in admin footer. I have two methods for this solution.

**#1 method**

```
function add_admin_footer(){
 ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 1, insert_url, shorten_url;

    function myplugin_tinymce_setup( editor ){

     editor.onNodeChange.add(function(ed, cm, e) {
          // Activates the link button when the caret is placed in a anchor element
          if (e.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a'){
            var element = jQuery(e).not('a[href="_wp_link_placeholder"],a[data-wplink-edit="true"]');
            if( element.length ){
              if( is_shorten = getShortenUrl( element.attr( 'href') ) ){ 
               element.attr( 'href', is_shorten );
               element.attr( 'data-mce-href', is_shorten );
              }
            }
          }

      });

 var hostname = new RegExp(location.host);
    var shorten_host = new RegExp('http://www.example.com'); // enter your short url generate host name
    function getShortenUrl( url ){
        // add more condition here...
        // Add here ajax or shorten javascript api etc.
        // filter and return short url
        if( hostname.test( url ) ){
           // internal link  
           // Return internal url with shorten
           return 'http://www.example.com/Internal/'+counter++;     

        }else if( shorten_host.test( url ) ){
          // not update already update with shorten url
          return false; 

        }else{
          // Return external url with shorten
          return 'http://www.example.com/External/'+counter++;  
        }

    }
</script>
 <?php
```

[image: WP link shorten in editor]

**#2 method**

```
function add_admin_footer(){
 ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 1, insert_url, shorten_url;

    function myplugin_tinymce_setup( editor ){

        editor.on('ExecCommand', function(e) {

            // Eexcute command when click on button apply on insert/edit link
           if( e.command == 'wp_link_apply' ){

              if( editor.selection.getContent() ){
                element = tinymce.$(editor.selection.getContent()); // Create new link 
              }else{
                element = tinymce.$(editor.selection.getNode()); // Edit link option 
              }
              if( element.prop('tagName').toLowerCase() == 'a' ){
                  current_link_url = element.attr('href'); // Real url added in editor.
                  // and also check current_link_url is not shorten url
                  // add more logic here. Get short url using ajax or bitly javascript api. 
                  if( is_shorten_url = getShortenUrl( element.attr('href')) ){
                    editor.execCommand('mceInsertLink',false,{ href: is_shorten_url });  
                  }

              }
           }

        });
    }

    var hostname = new RegExp(location.host);
    var shorten_host = new RegExp('http://www.example.com'); // enter your short url generate host name
    function getShortenUrl( url ){
        // add more condition here...
        // Add here ajax or shorten javascript api etc.
        // filter and return short url
        if( hostname.test( url ) ){
           // internal link  
           // Return internal url with shorten
           return 'http://www.example.com/Internal/'+counter++;     

        }else if( shorten_host.test( url ) ){
          // not update already update with shorten url
          return false; 

        }else{
          // Return external url with shorten
          return 'http://www.example.com/External/'+counter++;  
        }

    }

  </script>
 <?php  

}
```

Best of luck :)